# How to filter by joinloaded table in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Lets say I got 2 models, `Document` and `Person`. `Document` got relationship to `Person` via "owner" property. Now:

```
session.query(Document)\
    .options(joinedload('owner'))\
    .filter(Person.is_deleted!=True)
```

Will double join table `Person`. One person table will be selected, and the doubled one will be filtered which is not exactly what I want cuz this way document rows will not be filtered.

What can I do to apply filter on joinloaded table/model ?

Answer (score 24):

You are right, table `Person` will be used twice in the resulting `SQL`, but each of them serves different purpose:

- one is to filter the the condition: `filter(Person.is_deleted != True)`
- the other is to eager load the relationship: `options(joinedload('owner'))`

But the reason your query returns wrong results is because your filter condition is not complete. In order to make it produce the right results, you also need to JOIN the two models:

```
qry = (session.query(Document).
        join(Document.owner). # THIS IS IMPORTANT
        options(joinedload(Document.owner)).
        filter(Person.is_deleted != True)
        )
```

This will return correct rows, even though it will still have 2 references (JOINs) to `Person` table. The real solution to your query is that using [contains_eager](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/loading_relationships.html#sqlalchemy.orm.contains_eager) instead of [joinedload](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/loading.html#sqlalchemy.orm.joinedload):

```
qry = (session.query(Document).
        join(Document.owner). # THIS IS STILL IMPORTANT
        options(contains_eager(Document.owner)).
        filter(Person.is_deleted != True)
        )
```