# How to eager load optionally exists filtered relation

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm working on SQLAlchemy 0.9.8

This question is related to "[How to filter by joinloaded table in SqlAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7793842/3804019)" but not the same.

I have `Article` entity, and it's **optionally** localized by `ArticleL10n` entity.

```
Base = declarative_base()

class Article(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
    l10n = relationship("ArticleL10n",
            collection_class=attribute_mapped_collection('lang'),
            cascade="all, delete-orphan")

class ArticleL10n(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'article_10n'
    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'), primary_key=True)
    lang = Column(String(15), primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(255))
```

I want to query `Article` list with eager loading `ArticleL10n` of specific language.

I've tried:

```
session.query(Article) \
    .outerjoin(Article.l10n) \
    .options(contains_eager(Article.l10n)) \ 
    .filter(ArticleL10n.lang == "en") \
    .all()
```

This doesn't work, because if the article does not have `"en"` localization, it would be filtered out.

My current working code is this:

```
session.query(Article) \
    .outerjoin(ArticleL10n, and_(ArticleL10n.article_id == Article.id, ArticleL10n.lang == "en")) \
    .options(contains_eager(Article.l10n)) \ 
    .all()
```

This seems to work. But I don't like this because `ArticleL10n.article_id == Article.id` part looks like superfluous. I believe there should be a better way to do this.

How can I simplify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `relationship` directly instead of the join condition for the first part of your `join`:

```
.outerjoin(ArticleL10n, and_(Article.l10n, ArticleL10n.lang == "en"))
```