# SQLAlchemy filter related subquery

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

```
class Poll(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False)
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
    answers = db.relationship('Answer', backref='poll')

class Answer(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    poll_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Poll.id), nullable=False)
    title = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=False, nullable=False)
    votes = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    is_deleted = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    created_date = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)

poll = PollModel.query.join(
    PollModel.answers
).options(
    subqueryload(PollModel.answers.query)
).filter(
    PollModel.id == poll_id,
    PollModel.is_deleted == False,
)[0]
```

I am trying to filter the related answers that I subquery by the "is_deleted" attribute. But I keep ending up only filtering the polls on whether or not it has a non deleted answer. How do you filter a related object via subquery.

Comment: I think you need to work with `contains_eager` to achieve this. Please take a look at the documentation for this option. Also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7804059/99594) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
poll = Poll.query.filter(and_(Poll.id == poll.id, Poll.answers.any(is_deleted == False)).first()
```